# Link superclass init method to designated initializer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, init

Since every class inherits the initializer from the superclass this is how I have linked
the default implementation of `init` to its designated initializer. (It's working.)

Link:

```
-(id)init {
    return [self initWithItemName:@"Default Value" 
                    valueInDollar:0 
                     serialNumber:@""];
}
```

Initializer:

```
-(id)initWithItemName:(NSString *)myItemName
        valueInDollar:(int)myValueInDollar
         serialNumber:(NSString *)mySerialNumber;
```

My question is, do I ALWAYS have to link my own initializer the way I did it (Link)? 
So WITHOUT the code below own initializers would never be called? Am I right?

```
-(id)init {
    return [self myInitMethod......"];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only initialize your object with `initWithItemName`, then you don't have to define the `init` method at all. The initializers are just ordinary methods (no magic involved), so what you call is what will be invoked. But it is good practice to implement the `init` method so it can be called and the object will be in a consistent state.